# Detecting AOL Browser

Tags: php, browser

I was wondering if anyone could tell me what the user agents were for AOL and the AOL Browser? I need to display a message to visitors of my site that AOL is NOT compatible.

My plan using PHP is to do something similar to:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'AOL') == false)
 return false;
else
 return true;
```

Comment: AOL browser? Didn't they stop making those ages ago, and went onto making modified versions of IE8 and IE9? None the less, [THIS](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/AOL/) should be what you want.

Comment: They only ever had their "keyword" browser thing, but the actual browser they used when going to a url was to spawn a internet explorer window, so actually your site should be compatiable as long as its internet explorer compatible.

Comment: I dont think this fairly marked as too localized.  I am here because I am creating a website for a customer. Customer had an issue with the site. and low and behold when I was in his office. He was in the aol client browsing on XP.

Answer (score 1):

AOL didnt really have its own browser, it would spawn a Internet Explorer window, but the useragent strings that had AOL in them can be found here http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/AOL/